Will I still be able to get 165hz
So if I had a Nintendo and I got a 27 inch monitor that has 165 hz refresh rate, will I be able to use that 165hz or not because I’m using a nintendo.

Can you use the monitor in the meantime, yes absolutely. Will you actually be using the full 165hz? Definitely not, the Switch is locked at 60fps docked and 30fps handheld.

I assume that when you say a "nindendo", you're talking about a Nintendo Switch.
Assuming the monitor has either a HDMI input, or you have the correct adapters to connect the Switch Dock's HDMI output to the monitor. Then yes, you will almost certainly be able to use the 165hz monitor to play a Nintendo Switch... or any other Nintendo that can be connected to a modern monitor for that matter.
But even though the monitor  will be able to display the video coming from the Nintendo, the console will not be capable of outputting 165fps. The maximum frame rate of the Nintendo Switch is 60fps when it is docked, and 30fps when it is in handheld mode. Some other games consoles are capable of higher framerates though but I'm not aware of any that are capable of 165hz. For that, you'd need a PC.
